# Creating a Setup.exe file in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, installation

I have looked around on many Youtube videos but I was not able to find a good one that made sense since they were either old or not clear in explaining it. So I decided to come here. I'm so sorry for my bad grammar and not being able to explain things too well.

I can't figure out on how to use "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects" extension, since I do not know what are files to add into the "Application Folder" section. For the User Desktop, I am guessing it would be just a shortcut and the .ico file with it just excluded so the shortcut can have the icon with it also.

Thanks in advance,

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your project output(.exe) and all of its .dll in the Application Folder. For the shortcut, you can set the application's icon on the application properties:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vtzz.png

Once you're finished, you can build the project. And you will see a installer on the installer project's debug folder.

Comment: I have added all the files form the bin\Release to the "Application Files folder" on the setup folder. I have also added a shortcut and linked the icon to it in the "User Desktop".  I just cant figure out how to build it to get the final .exe now, sorry for me not knowing much :(

Comment: Right click to the Installer Project then click Build. You will see the installer on the bin\Debug on the Installer Project. That's it. :)

Comment: Now when I go to try to install it on my parents computer the "Program Name" comes up "E:\..." it shows the entire path not just Afk Bot. Also the Publisher field come up "Unknown". Also when i go in to "Program Files (86) the path to the files is.. C:\Program Files (x86)\Jaconah\AfkBot-Setup\AFK_Bot When i want it to just be C:\Program Files (x86)\AFK_Bot. I have only looked in to these a tiny bit now if I come across how to fix it I will comment and say that I was able to fix it, so you do not have to take time out of your day tell me.  I been looking for just under an hour now.. :'(

Comment: You can edit those Publisher name, Company name, etc. on the properties window of the Installer Project.

Comment: I did not want them to show up in the directory like that at all, i just wanted it to be the default C:/Program Files (x86)\Afk_Bot and not have all the extar directories in thier

Comment: You can set the Company name to Afk_Bot - C:\Program Files (x86)\\[Company Name]

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps, it's old but still applies:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/

Comment: That is a lot more advanced then i am trying to do. Due to that most of that is way above my head since i don't even need to touch the registry as far as i know, it not like its a paid program or anything special, it just a simple afk bot for a game that i made for a friend.

Comment: So i found out i was just messing a product code. Now when I go to try to install it on my parents computer the "Program Name" comes up "E:\..." it shows the entire path not just Afk Bot. Also the Publisher field come up "Unknown".  

Also when i go in to  "Program Files (86) the path to the files is.. C:\Program Files (x86)\Jaconah\AfkBot-Setup\AFK_Bot  When i want it to just be C:\Program Files (x86)\AFK_Bot.

I have only looked in to these a tiny bit now if I come across how to fix it I will comment and say that I was able to fix it, so you do not have to take time out of your day tell me.